# Unable to install Ubuntu 23.04 on Virtualbox 7.0.10

Tags: software-installation, 23.04

Whenever I am trying to install Ubuntu 23.04 on Virtualbox 7.0.10, it tells me that initial setup could not start. And gives me option to either wait or force quit. Even after waiting for long time, it does not start. And this has been happening since long.

Comment: so, your question is?

Comment: How much RAM are you assigning to the Virtual Machine?

Answer (score 1):

Virtual box 7.0.10 has been having problems post kernel 6.4.0

What does this mean.

linux-image-extra and linux-image-generic.
Are what you *might* need to install..
*MIGHT*.
This is not a sure-fire fix.

With out causing a commotion, in ubuntu 22.04 LTS it still gives headaches.

You may be forced to run the default "maintained" Ubuntu version of Virtual box.
I believe it's 6.1 or something.

Run from terminal: apt search virtualbox*

To see what the "community maintained" version is.

If you're dead set on running the latest and greatest, on a "vanilla" installation you may have to be a bit more patient.

Or look into different kernel options to full fill having version 7 running.